# UPDATE and SELECT from same table in one query

Tags: mysql, select, join, sql-update

I am trying to count the rows from table1, and depending the rows count to update a certain column. Below is the query I have tried, but am getting an arror saying that temp is not a table.

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table1 AS temp ON temp.id = t1.id
SET
t1.field1 = (CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp WHERE temp.field1 = 1) < 100 THEN 1
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp WHERE temp.field1 = 2) < 100 THEN 2
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp WHERE temp.field1 = 3) < 100 THEN 3
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp WHERE temp.field1 = 4) < 100 THEN 4
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp WHERE temp.field1 = 5) < 100 THEN 5
END)
WHERE t1.id IN(100, 200, 300); --Example data
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

1. I would suggest making a  temp table of the data in your case
   statement, then joining that for an update.
2. Joining back on the table you're updating does not work.
3. You have a syntax error in your where clause. You don't need that
   equals sign before IN.

Try:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table1 AS
SELECT field1,count(*) as field_count FROM table1 group by field1;

UPDATE table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN temp_table1 aa
  ON aa.field1= t1.field1
SET t1.field1 = (CASE 
  WHEN aa.field1 = 1 AND aa.field_count < 100 THEN 1 
  WHEN aa.field1 = 2 AND aa.field_count < 100 THEN 2 
  WHEN aa.field1 = 3 AND aa.field_count < 100 THEN 3 
  WHEN aa.field1 = 4 AND aa.field_count < 100 THEN 4 
  WHEN aa.field1 = 5 AND aa.field_count < 100 THEN 5 END)
WHERE t1.id IN (100, 200, 300);
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid doing the first because that table has more than 500k rows and eventually its going to be a performance issue copying them etc.Is there a way to do it without another temp table (joining and updating same table).

Comment: See my example. You don't need to replicate the entire table, just what you need for your case statement. Also, it's illegal to reopen the  table you're updating with a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Following query will be helpful to you,

```
UPDATE table1 as t1
SET
t1.field1 = (CASE         
    WHEN (select p.cnt from (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.field1= 1) as p) < 100 THEN 1
    WHEN (select p.cnt from (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.field1= 2) as p) < 100 THEN 2
    WHEN (select p.cnt from (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.field1= 3) as p) < 100 THEN 3
    WHEN (select p.cnt from (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.field1= 4) as p) < 100 THEN 4
    WHEN (select p.cnt from (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.field1= 5) as p) < 100 THEN 5    
 END)
WHERE t1.id IN(100, 200, 300)
```

Comment: You dont filter by id as I do above, in the join, but otherwise thats what I wanted.

Comment: For your requirement join make no sense. As far as your requirement is concerned above query is enough.